# AND chaining returns false even if both returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby hash like `{ :user_id => nil }`.

I print out:

```
    puts params.key? :user_id
    puts params[:user_id].nil?
    puts params.key? :user_id && params[:user_id].nil?
```

The output is:

```
true 
true
false
```

How come && chaning of 2 true results return false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sometimes you need parantheses

```
puts params.key? :user_id && params[:user_id].nil?
```

it's like

```
puts params.key?(:user_id && params[:user_id].nil?)
```

try

```
puts params.key?(:user_id) && params[:user_id].nil?
```